# How to indicate the start and end of thread in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm running a process in asp.net and I want the user to be aware when the process is running and when the process is over. This is the code I have

```
Private Sub test()
            For i As Integer = 0 To 1000 Step 1
                Thread.Sleep(100)
            Next
            Label1.Text = "Process Done"
    End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = "Progress Started"
        Dim MyTS As New ThreadStart(AddressOf test)
        Dim MyThead As New Thread(MyTS)
        MyThead.Start()
End Sub
```

I have put a thead.sleep in the process here because the code is quite extensive and will cause a considerable delay but then when I run the code and the label indicates "Process Started", it never indicate "process Done".

Comment: No exception? You're updating an UI element from a Non-UI-thread that should raise at least an exception...i guess

Comment: Well I get no exception except that "process Done" is never displayed.
However, how do I get around it anyway

Comment: You need to review how http protocol works. You do not have a connection from your server-side code to the client. A long-running process would probably be better placed in a Windows service, and you can search for "asp.net progress bar" for some suggestions on notifying the user.

Comment: Have you waited 2 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if an Invoke is required with **Me.Label1.InvokeRequired** and in case it is needed you Invoke a function to set the text.

Full example here: [Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.100).aspx)